unable to upload images into firebase storage in after deployment
I have flutter web app and uploading images works perfectly fine in debug mode but after i deployed it on firebase it's not working it's giving me this error

Upload error: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
here is my code:

  Future<void> profileUploader() async {
    await pickImage();
    if (imageFile != null) {
      isPhotoLoading.value = true;
      final Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('images/${currentUser!.uid}/profile/profile.png');

      final UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putData(imageFile!);
      uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
        // print('Task state: ${snapshot.state}');
        // print(
        //     'Progress: ${(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100} %');
      }, onError: (error) {
        Get.snackbar("Error", "$error",
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            colorText: Colors.black);
      });

      TaskSnapshot downloadUrlSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
      String downloadUrl = await downloadUrlSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> user = await FirebaseFirestore
          .instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('userId', isEqualTo: currentUser!.uid)
          .get();
      DocumentSnapshot userDocument = user.docs[0];
      DocumentReference userRef = userDocument.reference;
      try {
        await userRef.update({'profilePicture': downloadUrl});
        isPhotoLoading.value = false;
        Get.snackbar("Done", "Uploaded succesfully",
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            colorText: Colors.black);
        // Get.offAllNamed(Routes.customerProfile);s
      } catch (e) {
        isPhotoLoading.value = false;
        Get.snackbar("Error uploading please try again", "$e",
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            colorText: Colors.black);
      }
    }
  }


it was working before but today out of nowhere it stopped
i only deployed function to firebase that was my last thing
it's not permission error
i didn't do anything because i have no idea about the error

the problem was from http package i updated it from http: ^0.13.5 to http:^1.0.0
